# Doubts in Cauchy's integral theorem proof

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

**Theorem.** Let $f$ be an analytic, holomorphic function in an open, bounded and simply connected set $\tau$ and on its boundary $\partial \tau =\sigma$, with $\sigma$ closed, simple and piecewise regular curve. Then
$$f(z)=\oint_{\sigma} \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z} \text{d}\xi$$

My textbook proves the Cauchy's integral formula in the following way.

*Proof*. Isolate the point $z$ with a circumference $\sigma_{\delta}'$ with center $z$ and radius $\delta$, assuming $\delta$ small enough so that $\sigma_{\delta}'$ is contained in $\tau$.

Since $\sigma$ is simple, closed and piecewise regular and the function $g(\xi):=\frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z}$ is holomorphic in $\tau_{\delta}=\tau \setminus \{\xi\in\mathbb{C} \ \text{s.t.} |\xi-z| \leq \delta\}$ and in the closure $\bar{\tau}_\delta$, it follows that $\oint_{\sigma} \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z} \text{d}\xi=\oint_{\sigma_{\delta}'} \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z} \text{d}\xi$; letting $\xi=z+\delta e^{i\theta}$ with $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$, it is $\oint_{\sigma_{\delta}'} \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z} \text{d}\xi=i\int_0^{2\pi} f(z+\delta e^{i\theta}) \text{d}\theta$.

Observe that $\oint_{\sigma} \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z} \text{d}\xi$ is independent of $\delta$, so $i\int_0^{2\pi} f(z+\delta e^{i\theta}) \text{d}\theta$ is independent of $\delta$ as well; hence it is possible to evaluate the latter integral letting $\delta \to 0$.

Observe that $f$ is continuous as function of $(\theta,\delta)$ for $0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi$ and for $0 \leq \delta \leq \delta_0$ for an opportune $\delta_0$. So in all the closed interval $[0,\delta_0]$ the integral is a continuous function of $\delta$ and so we can exchange the integral and the limit, getting that $\lim_{\delta \to 0}i\int_0^{2\pi} f(z+\delta e^{i\theta}) \text{d}\theta=i\int_0^{2\pi}f(z)\text{d}\theta=2\pi i f(z)$ and so $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\sigma} \frac{f(\xi)}{\xi-z} \text{d}\xi=f(z)$. $\square$

I don't get why the author specify that there is an opportune $\delta_0$ such that $f$ is continuous w.r.t. $(\theta,\delta)$; what happens if $\delta_0$ isn't specified? Initially, I thought that if $\delta$ is too much big the circumference $\sigma_{\delta}'$ could exit from the analicity set $\tau$ of $f$, but, as it is written in the proof, the radius $\delta$ is already chosen such that it is contained in $\tau$. So there must be another reason that I'm missing, or maybe is just to quantify a closed interval for $\delta$ so that the theorem of interchange of limit and integral can be applied. Thank you.